# MPMoviePlayerController - customizing HTTP request(s)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, http, ios4, media-player

Is there a good way to add HTTP headers to requests made by MPMoviePlayer controller (and/or MediaPlayer in general)?

Not seeing any resonable way, I've tried to create my own protocol (with NSURLProtocol), that would extend NSURLRequest et. al. with the headers I want, but it seems that MediaPlayer.framework works directly with CFNetwork somehow, working around the standard URL loading system in some part.

A solution that would allow adding my own headers to **all** HTTP communication would be awesome as well.

Comment: Presumably you want to do this in order to communicate something back to your server?  Why not use part of the URL and use URL rewriting on the server side?